# Выдержит ли ymaps3 >10 000 кастомных меток?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Вопрос чисто теоретический, есть более 10 000 адресов по всему миру, их нужно отобразить, имеется ли у яндекс карт какой нибудь механизм, который там за overflow все точки разом не отобразит, а подгрузит только те, которые на текущих тайлах во вьюпорте?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не запретили собирать точки в кластеры - должно отработать. Попробуйте

Comment: Я чекал документацию ymaps3 и ничего про кластеризацию, как в 2.1 я не нашел

Comment: А не, нашел
https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/packages/clusterer/